# Is a function measurable on subset if its measurable on set?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose we have a set $E=E_1\cup E_2$, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint and measurable. $E$ is also measurable. Also, we have a function $f$ which is measurable on $E$. The question: is it measurable on $E_1$ and on $E_2$? Why?

Comment: It's hard to try something when I dont even realize is it true or not. By definition: E(f < x) = E1(f < x) U E2(f < x). But that's not enough for making decisions.

Comment: that notation seems to be a bit unusual. Maybe it could help you to specify the $\sigma$-algebra on $E1$.

Comment: I didnt get your idea, please, clarify how can I do this. We defined a measurable function as the function for which one of this sets is measurable: E(f < x), E(f <= x), E(f > x), E(f >= x).

Comment: I ran into this statement when I was reading about sigma-additivity of Lebesgue integral. That theorem used the idea that if the function is measurable and limited on E then it should be the same on E1 and E2. And then the integrals are exist.

Comment: Maybe another way of putting the question of @supinf is: What do you mean when you say "f is measurable on $E$", for example? Do you mean that $f$ is a $\sigma(E)$-measurable function?

Comment: I mean that at least one of Lebesgue sets above is measurable (if one of them is measurable then other are measurable too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got the answer.

$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}$ write $E_1 = A \cup B, E_2 = C \cup D$ where $A = E_1(f<k), C = E_2(f<k)$, then $E = A \cup B \cup C \cup D$. We know that $E(f < k)$ is measurable, it means that $A \cup C$ is measurable. Let's look at $ E \setminus E_1 \setminus E(f < k) = D$. $D \in \mathcal{A} $ (sigma algebra), but $D = E_2(f >= k)$. Then $f$ is measurable on $E_2$. That's it.